# AD / Forms authentication

Tags: .net, windows, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am developing an application that will mainly be used internally and want to know how i can automatically authenticate users against Active Directory without prompting them to login.

However, when a user is not automatically authenticated (i.e. they have connected via the internet)  I want to display a form that will authenticate the user against AD

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of ASP.NET you want to mix Windows and Forms Authentication. There is no simple solution. The possible workarounds are already discussed here:

[Mixing Windows Authentication with Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184873/mixing-windows-authentication-with-forms-authentication)